# Folland: Why is the product measure well-defined?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, product-measure

Consider the following fragment from Folland's "Real analysis" on p64:

[image]

I don't understand why $\pi(E)$ is well-defined, i.e. assume that
$$E = \bigcup_i A_i \times B_i= \bigcup_j C_j \times D_j$$
where the unions are disjoint. Then why is it true that
$$\sum_i \mu(A_i)\nu(B_i) = \sum_j \mu(C_j)\nu(D_j)?$$

Folland talks about a common refinement, but I don't see how that works.

Comment: Why the downvote? If someone can tell me how to improve my question, I will gladly try so.

Comment: You wrote only three sentence, all lacking context.  Copying and pasting an image, when you are clearly capable of formatting in mathjax, that makes this, essentially, a problem statement questions.  You posted a lazy question with minimal effort on your part;  Yet you seem to expect answerers put in more effort than you.  Tip: NONE of us, not EVEN mods, are paid to answer anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we can write $E=\bigcup_{i,j}(A_i\times B_i)\cap(C_j\times D_j)=\bigcup_{i,j}(A_i\cap C_j)\times(B_i\cap D_j)$.

So: $A_i\times B_i=\bigcup_{j}(A_i\cap C_j)\times(B_i\cap D_j)$, $C_j\times D_j=\bigcup_{i}(A_i\cap C_j)\times(B_i\cap D_j)$.

So we have: $\mu(E)=\mu(\bigcup_i A_i\times B_i)=\mu(\bigcup_{i,j}(A_i\cap C_j)\times(B_i\cap D_j))=\sum_{i,j}\mu_1(A_i\cap C_j)\mu_2(B_i\cap D_j)$

Now:

$\sum_{i}\mu_1(A_i)\mu_2(B_i)=\sum_{i,j}\mu_1(A_i\cap C_j)\mu_2(B_i\cap D_j)=\sum_j\mu_1(C_j)\mu_2(D_j)$, where the last step is true because I can change order of summation (everything is non-negative).

Answer (score 11):

Let's show how a common refinement works in a concrete example. This will get the idea across, and it's fairly clear that this works for any region you like.

Say $E$ is a set that can be written as a disjoint union of finitely many rectangles. For instance, this region
(pardon the paint):

[image: a region]

Now we define the area (measure) of this region to be the sum of the areas (measures) of the rectangles in a decomposition. For instance, we can witness this region as a disjoint union

[image: the first covering]

and define the area of $E$ to be the sum of the areas of these three rectangles (of course, we know what the area of a rectangle should be).

But wait, you say! What if instead we chose *this* decomposition:

[image: a second decomposition]

then the area of $E$ should be the sum of the areas of *these* three rectangles! But that might give us a different answer. How can we guarantee that we get the same result no matter which decomposition we choose?

Here's the secret: Overlay the two pictures on top of each other:

[image: the two pictures overlaid]

When we do this, it subdivides each of our previous regions into more rectangles.

[image: the common refinement]

When we subdivide our rectangles, we call this a *refinement* of our covering. But we've cleverly chosen these new rectangles to be a refinement of *both* of our coverings of interest. That is, it's a *common refinement*.

And now we see that the area of $E$ as measured by the first covering is the same as the area measured by the second covering. Why? Because *both* are the same as the area measured by the purple covering. After all,

[image: a labeled version of the refined diagram]

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{area}(\text{red}_1 + \text{red}_2 + \text{red}_3) 
&=
\text{area}(
\text{purple}_1 + 
(\text{purple}_2 + \text{purple}_3 + \text{purple}_4) +
(\text{purple}_5 + \text{purple}_6
) \\
&=
\text{area}(
\text{purple}_2 + 
(\text{purple}_3 + \text{purple}_5) +
(\text{purple}_1 + \text{purple}_4 + \text{purple}_6)
) \\
&=
\text{area}( \text{blue}_1 + \text{blue}_2 + \text{blue}_3)
\end{aligned}
$$

Where I haven't labelled the red/blue regions explicitly (mainly because I'm lazy), but hopefully it's clear from context.

So we see that, as long as we can find a common refinement, we can run this same argument. The area as computed by a covering is the same as the area computed by any of its refinements (this is basically additivity of a measure on disjoint sets), so if two coverings have a common refinement, they must give the same area.

Now, since a common refinement *always* exists (this is annoying to prove formally, but should be intuitively obvious), this means any two coverings of the same region give the same area, which is exactly what we wanted to show!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Beautiful answer.

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks ^_^

Comment: Thanks for your beautifully visual answer! Doesn't the other answer give a simpler proof though (it doesn't seem to hard to prove that this common refinement exists, when looking at that answer!)

Comment: @user839372 If you meditate on it for a bit, you'll find that the two proofs are the same

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I will. I find it hard to choose which answer to accept, as both answers deal with different aspects.

Comment: @user839372 This answer gave the geometric motivation to my answer, but practically they're exactly the same

Comment: @user839372 if you want to bounty me and accept the other answer, I would be more than happy with that! But don't feel an obligation to bounty me if you don't want to ^_^

Comment: @HellaSurvivor You mentioned in the end that the common refinement always exists and said it is hard to prove it formally. How does one actually go about such proof? I posted a related question here and wonder if you could share a couple of insights: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4520510/why-does-equal-finite-disjoint-union-of-cartesian-product-have-common-refinement.

Comment: I would be interested the proof requested by @Mathematics_Beginner as well!

Comment: @SimonSMN I might have figured out a proof for it using a recursive construction and the idea provided by Mason in the link shared by me above: intersections.

Comment: @Mathematics_Beginner Hey, yes, Mason's idea seems to do it. Happy days.